# How to re-enable wayland in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, login, wayland

I recently experimented with i3 (sudo apt install i3 -> reboot -> select  i3 from login screen cog) and decided to go back to gnome3 with wayland. However upon removing i3 it appears that the default login screen no longer shows the option to start gnome wayland session. The reason for wanting to use wayland is easy out of the box support for 144hz screen and having no issues with it so far. Login screen does not show option "Gnome on wayland" as previously. I would like to have it the way it used to be: input password and enjoy 18.04 LTS with gnome 3 on wayland with 144hz enabled. I have set WaylandEnable = true in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and restarted multiple times to no luck. Heres a bit of info:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS x86_64

Kernel: 4.20.0-042000-generic

Shell: bash 4.4.19

Resolution: 2560x1440

DE: GNOME 3.28.3

WM: GNOME Shell

Terminal: gnome-terminal

CPU: Intel i7-4790K (8) @ 4.500GHz

GPU: AMD Hawaii XT

Memory: 1077MiB / 32107MiB

Thanks in advance for help!

Edit: Downgrading kernel to 4.18.13-041813-generic solved the issue

Comment: Are you installing kernels from a PPA? I'm running into the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04.01, but the latest kernel version available is 4.18.0

Comment: I also "lost" the Gnome with Wayland option, not sure after doing what. 
I am on 18.04.2, with kernel 4.15.0-45-generic #48. I am trying to guess how to bring it back so if I find it out I will post here.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get login screen to show all sessions by switching to Kernel 4.18.13-04